# My custom JComponent is not showing up?

Tags: java

I want to make a simple test JComponent so that i can see how things work when calling repaint(), paintComponent() and overriding all of the methods in paint or update. This is for learning only I know that this would not be done in the real world.

To Start with I would like to just to be able to make a component that I can draw a line to x and y points. I want my JComponent class to have every method that should be in a JComponent class even if it is not used. Thus I would like a list of every method that needs to be overridden for creating ones own JComponent. (this is for later)

My main question is why will my component not render on my JPanel that I am using to draw all of my components on.

**Question: Why is my component not showing up on my JPanel?**

Also I would like to try and make this post a learning option for building a JComponent from scratch. I will add the working code at the bottom as I go and the code that does not work also.

Code:

```
package testpak;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.*;

public class FrameDemo {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    MyComponent cc = new MyComponent();

    FrameDemo() {
         setLookFeel();
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.pack();
         panel.add(cc);
         frame.add(panel);
         frame.setSize( new Dimension(200, 200));
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setLookFeel() {
         try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); 
         } catch (Exception ex) {

         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       FrameDemo fd = new FrameDemo();
    }
}
```

JComponent Class:

```
package testpak;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        paintComponent(g);
        paintBorder(g);
        paintChildren(g);
    }
}
```

New Code:

```
package testpak;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
         return new Dimension(100, 25);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

    public void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        super.paintBorder(g);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        paintComponent(g);
        paintBorder(g);
        paintChildren(g);
    }
}
```

Here is the new code. I set the preferred size and then am drawing a filled yellow rectangle and the a black border. The border does not appear to be showing on the bottom and right hand size. Can someone try this and see if it works for them.

Code that will throw and error

I tried to include these two methods into my JComponent. If I only have the first setSize(...) then everything works. If I also include the commented out version then I will receive and error.

```
    @Override
    public void setSize(Dimension d) {
        this.setSize(d);
    }

//  @Override
//  public void setSize(int x, int y) {
//      Dimension d = new Dimension(x,y);
//      this.setSize(d);
//  }
```

Error:

```
    at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
at testpak.MyComponent.setSize(MyComponent.java:15)
```

Answer (score 2):

`JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` which respects preferred sizes of components. You need to override `getPreferredSize` for `MyComponent`.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(500, 400);
}
```

Also only use `frame.pack()` instead of `setSize` before making the frame visible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the extra panel that you have in your code above, you can just do this:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
frame.add(cc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will ensure that your component fills the maximum available space on the frame.

Comment: Not a good solution. All Swing components should implement the getPreferredSize() (and minimum/maximum) methods to return an appropriate value. Then the component can be used with any layout manager.